# MySQL - 5 posts per category

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a schema like this:

```
Posts (id, title, created_on)
Categories (id, title, description)
Distributions (id, post_id*, category_id, main)
```

Each post in the `posts` table has 1 or more categories with only 1 main category.

I want to get 5 posts of each category with the following conditions:

- all posts must be older than 90 days
- for each category, posts are sorted by `created_on` in DESC

This is what I am thinking of but unable to get it right:

```
SELECT p.title, c.title, c.description FROM posts p, distributions d, categories c
  WHERE p.id = d.post_id
  AND d.category_id = c.id
  AND d.main = 1
  AND ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), p.created_on)) > 90
  GROUP BY c.id
  ORDER BY p.created_on DESC
  LIMIT 5;
```

I'm unsure at `limit 5`, whether it returns the top 5 rows of the joining table or 5 rows of each category group?

Any explanation would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way ca. 1992. Come. JOIN us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take use of session variables in MySQL since currently it doesn't support any analytic function. The subquery below will generate sequential number for each `category_title` and used that column to filter in the outer query.

```
SELECT  post_title, category_title, description
FROM
    (
        SELECT  p.title AS post_title, 
                c.title AS category_title, 
                c.description 
                @counter := IF(@current_category = c.title, @counter + 1, 1) AS counter,
                @current_category := c.title
        FROM    posts p, distributions d, categories c
        WHERE   p.id = d.post_id
                AND d.category_id = c.id
                AND d.main = 1
                AND ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), p.created_on)) > 90
        ORDER   BY p.created_on DESC
    ) s
WHERE   counter <= 5
```

Although the structure is not the same, but this [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1eb9c6/1) will show you result of what the query does.

Answer (score -1):

```
select c.id,c.title,p.id,p.title,description,created_on from Categories as c
join Distributions as d on d.category_id = c.id
join Posts as p on p.id = d.post_id 
where ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), p.created_on)) > 90
ORDER BY p.created_on DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: This will return only 5 posts, not 5 posts per category.

Comment: And the main category is not considered